# How to remove redundancy when computing sums for many rings

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization

I have this code to compute the sum of the values in a matrix that are closer than some distance but further away than another. Here is the code with some example data:

```
square = [[ 3,  0,  1,  3, -1,  1,  1,  3, -2, -1],
   [ 3, -1, -1,  1,  0, -1,  2,  1, -2,  0],
   [ 2,  2, -2,  0,  1, -3,  0, -2,  2,  1],
   [ 0, -3, -3, -1, -1,  3, -2,  0,  0,  3],
   [ 2,  2,  3,  2, -1,  0,  3,  0, -3, -1],
   [ 1, -1,  3,  1, -3,  3, -2,  0, -3,  0],
   [ 2, -2, -2, -3, -2,  1, -2,  0,  0,  3],
   [ 0,  3,  0,  1,  3, -1,  2, -3,  0, -2],
   [ 0, -2,  2,  2,  2, -2,  0,  2,  1,  3],
   [-2, -2,  0, -2, -2,  2,  0,  2,  3,  3]]

def enumerate_matrix(matrix):
    """
    Enumerate the elements in the matrix.
    """
    for x, row in enumerate(matrix):
        for y, value in enumerate(row):
            yield x, y, value

def sum_of_values(matrix, d):
    """
    Calculate the sum of values based on specified conditions.
    """
    total_sum = 0
    for x, y, v in enumerate_matrix(matrix):
        U = x * x + x + y * y + y + 1
        if d * d * 2 < U < (d + 1) ** 2 * 2:
            total_sum += v
    return total_sum
```

For this case, I want to compute sum_of_values(square, x) for x in [0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5, 7.5, 8.5, 9.5]. This is fast enough but I also want to do it for much larger matrices and the code is then doing a lot of redundant computation.  How can I remove this redundancy?

For example:

```
import numpy as np
square = np.random.randint(-3, 4, size=(1000, 1000))
for i in range(1000):
    result = sum_of_values(square, i + 0.5)
    print(f"Sum of values: {result} {i}")
```

This is too slow as I will need to perform this calculation for thousands of different matrices. How can the redundant calculations in my code be removed?

The key problem I think is that enunerate_matrix should only be looking at cells in the matrix that are likely to be the right distance instead of repeatedly rechecking all the cells in the matrix .

---

## Timings

For a 400 by 400 matrix my code takes approx 26 seconds.

```
def calc_values(matrix, n):
    scores = []
    for i in tqdm(range(n)):
        result = sum_of_values(square, i + 0.5)
        scores.append(result)
    return scores

n = 400
square = np.random.randint(-3, 4, size=(n, n))
%timeit calc_values(square, n)
```

- RomanPerekhrest's code takes approx 119ms even including making the U_arrays matrix.
- Reinderien's code takes approx 149ms.

Comment: the first thing that comes to mind is that you should probably be using a vectorised method within the `numpy` module for this.

Comment: @D.L That sounds good. I think the biggest improvement would be to find a way to look at only cells that are likely to be in the right range .

Comment: Since this code is working but needs a performance review, consider re-posting on Code Review Stack Exchange.

Comment: Before you post at [codereview.se], be sure to read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778), as some things are done differently over there - e.g. question titles should simply say what the code *is for*, as the question is always, "How can I improve this?".  Be sure that the code works correctly; include your unit tests if possible.  You'll likely get some suggestions on making it more efficient, easier to read, and better tested.

Comment: Is it redundant because you are doing this on thousands of matrices that are all the same size? Are there a lot of different "d" values, or is it consistently integers, or are the d values often the same?

Comment: @KennyOstrom It's redundant because the code rechecks every cell in the matrix for every distance d. It should be clever enough to only check the ones that are likely to be relevant. For each matrix I look at all integer values of d +0.5 as in my example code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traverse the input `square` matrix just **once** to generate an array of pairs where calculated `U` parameter mapped to the respective *value*. 
Then apply a vectorized operation to sum up values filtered by `U` params matched the condition.

```
def make_U_array(mtx):
    """Make an array of (U, value) pairs"""
    arr = np.array([(x * x + x + y * y + y + 1, value)
                    for x, row in enumerate(mtx)
                    for y, value in enumerate(row)])
    return arr

def sum_values_by_cond(U_values, d):
    # mask values where U parameters fit the condition
    m = (d * d * 2 < U_values[:, 0]) & (U_values[:, 0] < (d + 1) ** 2 * 2)
    return np.sum(U_values[:, 1][m])
```

---

**Update**: alternative and faster version of `make_U_array` function based on [`np.indices`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.indices.html) (to get row/column indices), it should give about 3x time speedup compared to a previous *list-comprehension* approach:

```
def make_U_array(mtx):
    """Make an array of (U, value) pairs"""
    x, y = np.indices(mtx.shape)
    x, y = x.flatten(), y.flatten() # row/column indices
    arr = np.column_stack((x * x + x + y * y + y + 1, np.ravel(mtx)))
    return arr
```

---

Sample case (assuming you initial `square` array):

```
U_arr = make_U_array(square)

for i in range(10):
    result = sum_values_by_cond(U_arr, i + 0.5)
    print(f"Sum of values: {result} {i}")
```

---

```
Sum of values: 6 0
Sum of values: 3 1
Sum of values: -1 2
Sum of values: 4 3
Sum of values: 3 4
Sum of values: 3 5
Sum of values: -11 6
Sum of values: 4 7
Sum of values: 7 8
Sum of values: 3 9
```

Comment: This is still not fully vectorised - the outer sum is still a loop.

Comment: and in fact there's a triple loop due to your list comprehension, so this will perform poorly indeed.

Comment: @Reinderien, "there's a triple loop due to your list comprehension" - it's computed only once. Start comparing it with the former solution instead of complaining.

Comment: It's very fast! Thank you.

Comment: @Reinderien, "This is still not fully vectorised - the outer sum is still a loop" - I've optimized the core mechanism, in case you haven't "fully" noticed

Comment: I'm trying to help. The comprehension is an obvious miss, and produces timings slower than the einsum method by a factor of about 25. If you fix this I would be happy to include another version in my timings.

Comment: @Simd, please check the alternative version of `make_U_array` function

Comment: @Reinderien sorry, I couldn't take much from einsum, but managed with np.indices

Comment: You are in the lead :)

Answer (score 1):

You aim to compute the sum of `v[x, y]` for coordinates (x, y) satisfying `2d^2 < x^2 + x + y^2 + y + 1 < 2(d+1)^2` for different values of d.

Given `d` values like 0.5, 1.5, ..., 999.5, the condition ca

```
2d^2 < x^2 + x + y^2 + y + 1 < 2(d+1)^2
d^2 < (x^2 + x + y^2 + y + 1)/2 < (d+1)^2
d < sqrt((x^2 + x + y^2 + y + 1)/2) < d+1
# Since d is always an integer plus 0.5, the range can be adjusted:
d-0.5 < sqrt((x^2 + x + y^2 + y + 1)/2)-0.5 < d+0.5
```

To optimize, in your specific example, you can precompute sums and store them in an array. Let `sum_array` represent the array of the sums of v[x, y] for the changing `d`. You can create a function returning all results for `d = 0.5, 1.5, ..., n + 0.5`:

```
def sums_of_values(matrix, range_stop):
    """
    Calculate the sums of values based on specified conditions.
    """
    sum_array = np.zeros(range_stop, dtype=int)
    for x, y, v in enumerate_matrix(matrix):
        U = x * x + x + y * y + y + 1
        ind = int(np.sqrt(U/2)-0.5)
        if ind < range_stop:
            sum_array[ind] += v
    return sum_array
```

and then you can print like

```
import numpy as np
square = np.random.randint(-3, 4, size=(1000, 1000))
results = sums_of_values(square, 1000)
for i in range(1000):
    print(f"Sum of values: {results[i]} {i}")
```

Note that this uses a floating operation, which is slower than integer operations, so there could be some other improvements. Also, this requires some additional changes if the range of d is not like 0.5, 1.5, ....

Comment: I need it to be fast as I will do the computation on thousands of matrices.

Comment: Can you time your code on a 400 by 400 matrix outputting all the scores for d = np.arange(0, 400) + 0.5 as in the Timings section of the question?

Answer (score 0):

A fully-vectorised version with "nothing clever" looks like

```py
def vector_full(matrix: np.ndarray, nd: int = 10) -> np.ndarray:
    d = np.arange(0.5, nd)[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis]
    d_lo = d**2 * 2
    d_hi = (d + 1)**2 * 2
    _, y, x = np.indices((1, *matrix.shape), sparse=True)
    u = 1 + x*(x + 1) + y*(y + 1)
    mask = (d_lo < u) & (u < d_hi)
    return np.einsum('jk,ijk->i', matrix, mask)
```

### Timings

```py
from timeit import timeit
from typing import Iterator

import numpy as np


def op_method(matrix: np.ndarray, nd: int = 10) -> np.ndarray:
    def enumerate_matrix(matrix: np.ndarray) -> Iterator[tuple[int, int, float]]:
        """
        Enumerate the elements in the matrix.
        """
        for x, row in enumerate(matrix):
            for y, value in enumerate(row):
                yield x, y, value

    def sum_of_values(matrix: np.ndarray, d: float) -> float:
        """
        Calculate the sum of values based on specified conditions.
        """
        total_sum = 0
        for x, y, v in enumerate_matrix(matrix):
            U = x*x + x + y*y + y + 1
            if d*d*2 < U < (d + 1)**2 * 2:
                total_sum += v
        return total_sum

    def all_sums(matrix: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
        all_x = np.arange(0.5, nd)
        output = np.empty_like(all_x)
        for i, x in enumerate(all_x):
            output[i] = sum_of_values(matrix, x)
        return output

    return all_sums(matrix)


def roman_perekhrest_listcomp(matrix: np.ndarray, nd: int = 10) -> np.ndarray:
    def make_U_array(mtx):
        """Make an array of (U, value) pairs"""
        arr = np.array([(x * x + x + y * y + y + 1, value)
                        for x, row in enumerate(mtx)
                        for y, value in enumerate(row)])
        return arr

    def sum_values_by_cond(U_values, d):
        # mask values where U parameters fit the condition
        m = (d * d * 2 < U_values[:, 0]) & (U_values[:, 0] < (d + 1) ** 2 * 2)
        return np.sum(U_values[:, 1][m])

    U_arr = make_U_array(matrix)

    result = np.empty(nd)
    for i in range(nd):
        result[i] = sum_values_by_cond(U_arr, i + 0.5)
    return result


def roman_perekhrest_indices(matrix: np.ndarray, nd: int = 10) -> np.ndarray:
    def make_U_array2(mtx):
        """Make an array of (U, value) pairs"""
        x, y = np.indices(mtx.shape)
        x, y = x.flatten(), y.flatten()  # row/column indices
        arr = np.column_stack((x * x + x + y * y + y + 1, np.ravel(mtx)))
        return arr

    def sum_values_by_cond(U_values, d):
        # mask values where U parameters fit the condition
        m = (d * d * 2 < U_values[:, 0]) & (U_values[:, 0] < (d + 1) ** 2 * 2)
        return np.sum(U_values[:, 1][m])

    U_arr = make_U_array2(matrix)

    result = np.empty(nd)
    for i in range(nd):
        result[i] = sum_values_by_cond(U_arr, i + 0.5)
    return result


def naetmul(matrix: np.ndarray, nd: int = 10):
    def enumerate_matrix(matrix):
        """
        Enumerate the elements in the matrix.
        """
        for x, row in enumerate(matrix):
            for y, value in enumerate(row):
                yield x, y, value

    def sums_of_values(matrix, range_stop):
        """
        Calculate the sums of values based on specified conditions.
        """
        sum_array = np.zeros(range_stop, dtype=int)
        for x, y, v in enumerate_matrix(matrix):
            U = x*x + x + y*y + y + 1
            ind = int(np.sqrt(U / 2) - 0.5)
            if ind < range_stop:
                sum_array[ind] += v
        return sum_array

    return sums_of_values(matrix, range_stop=nd)


def vector_full(matrix: np.ndarray, nd: int = 10) -> np.ndarray:
    d = np.arange(0.5, nd)[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis]
    d_lo = d**2 * 2
    d_hi = (d + 1)**2 * 2
    _, y, x = np.indices((1, *matrix.shape), sparse=True)
    u = 1 + x*(x + 1) + y*(y + 1)
    mask = (d_lo < u) & (u < d_hi)
    return np.einsum('jk,ijk->i', matrix, mask)


METHODS = (
    vector_full,
    roman_perekhrest_indices,
    roman_perekhrest_listcomp,
    naetmul,
    op_method,
)


def test() -> None:
    square = np.array([
        [ 3,  0,  1,  3, -1,  1,  1,  3, -2, -1],
        [ 3, -1, -1,  1,  0, -1,  2,  1, -2,  0],
        [ 2,  2, -2,  0,  1, -3,  0, -2,  2,  1],
        [ 0, -3, -3, -1, -1,  3, -2,  0,  0,  3],
        [ 2,  2,  3,  2, -1,  0,  3,  0, -3, -1],
        [ 1, -1,  3,  1, -3,  3, -2,  0, -3,  0],
        [ 2, -2, -2, -3, -2,  1, -2,  0,  0,  3],
        [ 0,  3,  0,  1,  3, -1,  2, -3,  0, -2],
        [ 0, -2,  2,  2,  2, -2,  0,  2,  1,  3],
        [-2, -2,  0, -2, -2,  2,  0,  2,  3,  3],
    ])
    expected = [6, 3, -1, 4, 3, 3, -11, 4, 7, 3]

    for method in METHODS:
        actual = method(square)
        assert np.allclose(actual, expected, rtol=0, atol=1e-9)


def time() -> None:
    rand = np.random.default_rng(seed=0)

    for n in (10, 400):
        matrix = rand.random((n, n))
        for nd in (10, 400):
            if n == 10 and nd == 10:
                methods = METHODS
            else:
                methods = METHODS[:-1]
            for method in methods:
                def run():
                    return method(matrix, nd=nd)
                t = timeit(run, number=1)
                print(f'nd={nd:3}, {n:3}x{n:3}, {method.__name__:25}: {t:.5f}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
    time()
```

```
nd= 10,  10x 10, vector_full              : 0.00008
nd= 10,  10x 10, roman_perekhrest_indices : 0.00027
nd= 10,  10x 10, roman_perekhrest_listcomp: 0.00022
nd= 10,  10x 10, naetmul                  : 0.00024
nd= 10,  10x 10, op_method                : 0.00080
nd=400,  10x 10, vector_full              : 0.00024
nd=400,  10x 10, roman_perekhrest_indices : 0.00328
nd=400,  10x 10, roman_perekhrest_listcomp: 0.00348
nd=400,  10x 10, naetmul                  : 0.00018
nd= 10, 400x400, vector_full              : 0.00509
nd= 10, 400x400, roman_perekhrest_indices : 0.00736
nd= 10, 400x400, roman_perekhrest_listcomp: 0.10165
nd= 10, 400x400, naetmul                  : 0.19444
nd=400, 400x400, vector_full              : 0.13887
nd=400, 400x400, roman_perekhrest_indices : 0.09793
nd=400, 400x400, roman_perekhrest_listcomp: 0.19251
nd=400, 400x400, naetmul                  : 0.25905
```

### Alternative approaches

Left as an exercise to the reader, you could form a scipy sparse matrix for the mask, and then either

- sparse matrix-multiply with the matrix and loop to the output array, or
- grab non-zero indices from the sparse matrix, index into the matrix, sum and loop to the output array.

These will definitely help with memory if that's a factor, but it's difficult to guess whether they will be faster.

Comment: Can you time your code on a 400 by 400 matrix outputting all the scores for d = np.arange(0, 400) + 0.5. It seems quite a lot slower than my posted code, at least before your last einsum update.

Comment: @Simd see timings.

Comment: Did you time with np.arange(0.5, n, 1) with n = 400?  I just did and it is very fast, not as fast as your results.

Comment: I have now. This still appears to be the most efficient method, with more dramatic differences for small `nd`.

Comment: Your results are much the same as mine now (I added them to the question). I am only interested in larger nd. Thanks so much. Do you think this is the limit to the possible speedups?

Comment: No - there is more that can be done