# Compute the max sum circular area

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, performance, optimization

I have an n by n matrix of integers and I want to find the circular area, with origin at the top left corner, with maximum sum.  Consider the following grid with a circle imposed on it.

[image]

This is made with:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Circle
import numpy as np
plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 10.01, 1))
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 10.01, 1))
plt.xlim(0,9)
plt.ylim(0,9)
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
# Set aspect ratio to be equal
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
plt.grid()   
np.random.seed(40)
square = np.empty((10, 10), dtype=np.int_)
for x in np.arange(0, 10, 1):
    for y in np.arange(0, 10, 1):
        plt.scatter(x, y, color='blue', s=2, zorder=2, clip_on=False) 
for x in np.arange(0, 10, 1):
    for y in np.arange(0, 10, 1):
        value = np.random.randint(-3, 4)
        square[int(x), int(y)] = value
        plt.text(x-0.2, y-0.2, str(value), ha='center', va='center', fontsize=8, color='black')

r1 = 3
circle1 = Circle((0, 0), r1,  color="blue", alpha=0.5, ec='k', lw=1)
plt.gca().add_patch(circle1)
```

In this case the matrix is:

```
[[ 3  0  2 -3 -3 -1 -2  1 -1  0]
 [-1  0  0  0 -2 -3 -2  2 -2 -3]
 [ 1  3  3  1  1 -3 -1 -1  3  0]
 [ 0  0 -2  0  2  1  2  2 -1 -1]
 [-1  0  3  1  1  3 -2  0  0 -1]
 [-1 -1  1  2 -3 -2  1 -2  0  0]
 [-3  2  2  3 -2  0 -1 -1  3 -2]
 [-2  0  2  1  2  2  1 -1 -3 -3]
 [-2 -2  1 -3 -2 -1  3  2  3 -3]
 [ 2  3  1 -1  0  1 -1  3 -2 -1]]
```

When the circle has radius 3, there are 11 points in the grid within the circle.  As the radius increases, more and more points fall into the circle.

I am looking for a fast way to find a radius which maximizes the sum of the integers of grid points within it.  The radius will not be unique so any one that maximizes the sum is ok. I will ultimately want to do this with much larger matrices.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77707524/how-to-remove-redundancy-when-computing-sums-for-many-rings) is related but I am not sure how to extend it to my new question.

Comment: How are there 11 points within a quarter of a circle with radius 3? Also, `Circle` is undefined.

Comment: @Nin17  They are at (0,0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (2, 0), (1, 1), (0,2), (3, 0), (2, 1), (1, 2), (0, 3) and (2, 2). Thanks for the Circle comment. Definition added.

Comment: My first thoughts about this is that it's only possible using brute force since there isn't really any consistent relationship between radius and sum.

Comment: @jared I am hoping it's possible to work out a minimal set of radiuses (radii?) where you get a different set of points inside the circle and then incrementally add the points as you go through those radiuses. But I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Sort points by distance to origin, then sum together points with same distance and use prefix sums.

Comment: @qwr Do you think it can be solved in O(n^2) time? That is without sorting.

Comment: Sorting will only take O (n^2 log (n)) time. Any other method I can think of is equivalent to sorting.

Comment: If the log factor really matters, I would write it in C++.

Comment: @qwr I need to call it from python, which is the problem.

Comment: Actually you may not need to sort, just accumulate by distance and then prefix sum.

Comment: @qwr Would you be happy to show code for that? (please)

Comment: Well you still need to sort by distance, or keep a large array of total distances with a bunch of zeros that is probably not faster than sorting.

Comment: how many distances are less than 10? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau%E2%80%93Ramanujan_constant?wprov=sfla1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same O(n^2 log n) method as others: accumulate weight sums by distance, then compute cumulative sums. But in pure python which should be trivial to translate to C++. Also PyPy may run surprisingly fast.

```
from collections import Counter

g = [[-3, 2, 2],
     [ 2, 0, 3],
     [-1, -2, 0]]
n = 3

sum_dist = Counter()
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        dist = i**2 + j**2
        sum_dist[dist] += g[i][j]

sorted_dists = sorted(sum_dist.keys())
for i in range(1, len(sorted_dists)):
    sum_dist[sorted_dists[i]] += sum_dist[sorted_dists[i-1]]

print(sum_dist)
print(max(sum_dist, key=sum_dist.get))
```

Comment: I love pypy but you sadly can't use it to speed up an individual function.

Comment: Stepping through the grid is easy to parallelize with an atomic Counter. Probably a way to do prefix sums in parallel too.

Comment: Numpy probably has a way to map and reduce the grid values by dist, and cumsum.

Comment: That would be cool

Comment: added a numpy version that runs 1 million points in 118ms.

Answer (score 4):

SORT the points in terms of radius (O(N.log(N)) )

Create a parallel array with the cumulative sum of the weights. (O(N))

Ensure in that parallel array that all points with the same radius have the same cumulative sum (O(N))

Identify the index of the biggest element of that last array. (O(N))

N = side^2, so complexity would be O(side^2 log(side))

**EDIT** - as requested, some code.
Python version (bit naive):

```
import math
import numpy as np

class Node:
   def __init__( self, x, y, w ):
        self.x, self.y = x, y          # original coordinates
        self.rsq = x * x + y * y       # radius squared
        self.w = w;                    # weight

init_data = [ [ 3,  0,  2, -3, -3, -1, -2,  1, -1,  0],
              [-1,  0,  0,  0, -2, -3, -2,  2, -2, -3],
              [ 1,  3,  3,  1,  1, -3, -1, -1,  3,  0],
              [ 0,  0, -2,  0,  2,  1,  2,  2, -1, -1],
              [-1,  0,  3,  1,  1,  3, -2,  0,  0, -1],
              [-1, -1,  1,  2, -3, -2,  1, -2,  0,  0],
              [-3,  2,  2,  3, -2,  0, -1, -1,  3, -2],
              [-2,  0,  2,  1,  2,  2,  1, -1, -3, -3],
              [-2, -2,  1, -3, -2, -1,  3,  2,  3, -3],
              [ 2,  3,  1, -1,  0,  1, -1,  3, -2, -1] ]

rows, cols = len( init_data ), len( init_data[0] )
N = rows * cols;

# Set up structure of nodes
A = []
for i in range( rows ):
    for j in range( cols ):
        A.append( Node( i, j, init_data[i][j] ) )

# Sort node structure
A.sort( key=lambda x: x.rsq )

# Sum of weights
sumWt = np.ndarray( N, dtype="int" )
sumWt[0] = A[0].w
for k in range( 1, N ): sumWt[k] = sumWt[k-1] + A[k].w

# Now make sure that all points at the same radius have the same sum of weights
sumWt2 = sumWt.copy()
p = 0
while p < N:
    q = p + 1
    while q < N and A[q].rsq == A[p].rsq: q += 1
    sumWt2[p:q] = sumWt2[q-1]
    p = q

# Debugging line ...
# for a, w, w2 in zip( A, sumWt, sumWt2 ): print( a.x, a.y, a.rsq, w, w2 )

# Identify best
pos = sumWt2.argmax()
r = math.sqrt( A[pos].rsq )
print( "Radius: ", r )
print( "Best sum: ", sumWt2[pos] )
```

Output:

```
Radius:  2.8284271247461903
Best sum:  11
```

**C++ version**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

struct Node
{
   int x, y;       // original coordinates
   int rsq;        // radius squared
   int w;          // weight
};

int main()
{
   vector< vector<int> > init_data =
         { { 3,  0,  2, -3, -3, -1, -2,  1, -1,  0 },
           {-1,  0,  0,  0, -2, -3, -2,  2, -2, -3 },
           { 1,  3,  3,  1,  1, -3, -1, -1,  3,  0 },
           { 0,  0, -2,  0,  2,  1,  2,  2, -1, -1 },
           {-1,  0,  3,  1,  1,  3, -2,  0,  0, -1 },
           {-1, -1,  1,  2, -3, -2,  1, -2,  0,  0 },
           {-3,  2,  2,  3, -2,  0, -1, -1,  3, -2 },
           {-2,  0,  2,  1,  2,  2,  1, -1, -3, -3 },
           {-2, -2,  1, -3, -2, -1,  3,  2,  3, -3 },
           { 2,  3,  1, -1,  0,  1, -1,  3, -2, -1 } };

   int rows = init_data.size();
   int cols = init_data[0].size();
   int N = rows * cols;

   // Set up node structure
   vector<Node> A( N );
   int k = 0;
   for ( int i = 0; i < rows; i++ )
   {
      for ( int j = 0; j < cols; j++ )
      {
         A[k] = { i, j, i * i + j * j, init_data[i][j] };
         k++;
      }
   }

   // Sort node structure
   sort( A.begin(), A.end(), []( Node &a, Node &b ){ return a.rsq < b.rsq; } );

   // Sum of weights
   vector<int> sumWt( N );
   sumWt[0] = A[0].w;
   for ( int k = 1; k < N; k++ ) sumWt[k] = sumWt[k-1] + A[k].w;

   // Now make sure that all points at the same radius have the same sum of weights
   auto sumWt2 = sumWt;
   for ( int p = 0, q; p < N; p = q )
   {
      for ( q = p + 1; q < N and A[q].rsq == A[p].rsq; q++ );
      for ( int i = p; i < q; i++ ) sumWt2[i] = sumWt[q-1];
   }

// Debugging line ...
// for ( int k = 0; k < N; k++ ) cout << A[k].x << '\t' << A[k].y << '\t' << A[k].rsq << '\t' << sumWt[k] << '\t' << sumWt2[k] << '\n';

   int pos = max_element( sumWt2.begin(), sumWt2.end() ) - sumWt2.begin();
   double r = sqrt( A[pos].rsq );

   cout << "Radius " << r << '\n';
   cout << "Best sum " << sumWt2[pos] << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
Radius 2.82843
Best sum 11
```

Comment: Could you show code to do this?

Comment: Well, yes, but I write Python considerably slower than I write C++, so I've added C++ code to my answer. I hope that it's intelligible and you can translate it.

Comment: OK, I've added a (rather naive) Python version as well.

Comment: I think it might be buggy. It gives 5 for [[-3  2  2], [ 2  0  3], [-1 -2  0]] with radius sqrt(5) but I don't see that.

Comment: Yes, I've forgotten to group things with a common radius.

Comment: Well, I've fixed it so that the whole set of cumulative sums at the same radius have the same value (the last for that radius). I hope that's better (if a lot less tidy now).

Comment: you don't need to store all the info in Node. you can accumulate total distance in an ordered dict.

Comment: Fair point. My Python is certainly naive at the moment.

Comment: C++ standard library has a ordered map too I think. I think std::map by default is since it's a RB tree while unordered map is a hashmap.

Answer (score 3):

In my mind, a pandas DataFrame is the perfect data structure for this task. Here's how I reframed this problem setup to live in a df:

```
from itertools import product

x = np.arange(0,10,1)
y = np.arange(0,10,1)
xy = list(product(x,y))

df = pd.DataFrame(xy, columns=['x', 'y'])
df['score'] = np.random.randint(-3,4,len(df))
```

[Here's what this dataframe will look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4V3gf.png)

We should have each point on the grid as well as the score associated with it. Now we need to find out how far each point on the grid is from the origin (which is also our circle's center point)

```
df['distance'] = (df['x']**2 + df['y']**2)
df = df.sort_values(by='distance')
```

Now we have every point on our grid sorted in ascending order by distance from the origin. At this point, we could jump right to a cumulative sum of the scores associated with each point and find when that cumulative sum is at a maximum. But we can add one additional step to handle when multiple points on the grid share a distance from the origin, collapsing their scores into the same row for our cumulative sum's benefit.

```
df = df.groupby('distance')['score'].sum().reset_index()
```

And now our cumulative sum.

```
df['cumulative_score'] = df['score'].cumsum()
```

We can find the argmax of `df['cumulative_score']` or plot it for a visual. In our case (given our randomly generated data) the answer is a tie between a radius of 2 and 3, which yields a sum within the circle of 3.

```
plt.plot(df['distance'], df['cumulative_score'])
```

[Plot of Total Score vs Radius of Circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5O4Z.png)

**EDIT**: Questioner asked if we could do this in NumPy

Sure we can do most of this easily in NumPy.

```
x = np.arange(0,10,1)
y = np.arange(0,10,1)
xy = list(product(x,y))
xy = np.array(xy)
scores = np.random.randint(-3,4,len(xy))

# calculate distances
distances = xy[:,0]**2 + xy[:,1]**2

# use argsort to find how we'd need to reorder things to sort distance ascending
sort_order = distances.argsort()

# sort our other arrays with this sort order
distances = distances[sort_order]
scores = scores[sort_order]
xy = xy[sort_order]

# group by unique distances, sum within group by radius length
unique_distances, unique_distances_ix = np.unique(distances, return_index=True)
scores_grouped = np.split(scores, unique_distances_ix[1:])
score_sums = [x.sum() for x in scores_grouped]

#cumulative sum
cumulative_scores = np.cumsum(score_sums)

print(np.argmax(cumulative_scores))
print(unique_distances[np.argmax(cumulative_scores)])

plt.plot(unique_distances, cumulative_scores)
plt.ylabel('Total Score')
plt.xlabel('Radius of Circle')
```

Note that using NumPy makes it *much* harder to handles ties as we did in Pandas. The above solution in NumPy does do it, but not as elegantly.

Comment: I would like to avoid a pandas dependency if possible. Can this be done in numpy? Also, if we are just sorting by distance, do we need to compute the square root ? That is the `**0.5` part,

Comment: it suffices to keep squared distance, which also gets rid of any floating point issues.

Comment: @Simd root is monotonic transformation so yes we can omit, I've updated my answer.

Comment: @Simd further, we can accomplish this with NumPy though it is not as easy to read. I've added a version without pandas dependency to my original answer

Comment: what kind of speed are you seeing? I think the pure numpy solution I posted should be faster.

Answer (score 2):

Simple and fast, using pure `numpy` (vectorized), 78 ms for 1 million points.

```py
import numpy as np

def rmaxsum(a):
    r = (np.indices(a.shape)**2).sum(0).ravel()
    ix = np.argsort(r)
    r = r[ix]
    j = np.flatnonzero(np.diff(r))
    rsum = a.ravel()[ix].cumsum()[j]
    imax = np.argmax(rsum)
    return r[j][imax], rsum[imax]
```

On the example provided:

```py
>>> rmaxsum(a)
(8, 11)
```

On a larger problem:

```py
np.random.seed(0)
n = 1000
a = np.random.randint(-10, 11, (n, n))

>>> rmaxsum(a)
(800293, 9524)

%timeit rmaxsum(a)
78.2 ms ± 256 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

#### Explanation

- `r` is the radius (distance from origin 0,0), squared, for each array cell.
- `ix` is the index that sorts these radii.
- `j` is the index of the *last* value of a given radius. For example, it starts by: `0, 2, 3, 5, 7`, that index the last location of a given radius**2 in: `0, 1, 1, 2, 4, 4, 5, 5`.
- `rsum` is the sum of all values within a given radius. Since it is "at `j`", a groupby for each same radius is implicitly done.

Comment: Very nice and fast!